# Regex doesn't recognize String C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, casting, pattern-matching

I'm working with Regex Class. I'm trying to figure it out, how many common matches a String
has in another String.

Here is the situation:

```
MainWindow.DetailBLL.Name = "Top Senders By Total Threat Messages"
String detailName = MainWindow.DetailBLL.Name;
```

Extracted from:

```
MainWindow = Window Class
DetailBLL = Class
Name = Variable

public String Name
{
    get { return _Name; }
    set { _Name = value; }
}

CharacterReplacement(openedFile) = "Incoming Mail Domains Top Senders By Total Threat Messages"
String fileName = CharacterReplacement(openedFile);
```

Extracted from:

```
OpenFileDialog openedFile = new OpenFileDialog();
```

Incoming_Mail_Domains_Top_Senders_by_Graymail_Messages_RawData.csv

```
private String CharacterReplacement(OpenFileDialog file)
{
    String input = file.SafeFileName;
    String output = input.Replace("_", " ").Replace("RawData", " ").Replace("by",      "By").Replace(".csv", " ");

    //output: "Incoming Mail Domains Top Senders By Graymail Messages"
    return output;
}
```

This method takes the file's name (The name of a .csv file) and convert it to a readable String, returning it as is depicted.

The use of the Regex Class:

```
String source = detailName;

String searchPattern = fileName;
```

1st try: Doesn't work

```
int count = Regex.Matches(searchPattern, source).Count;
```

or doesn't work

```
int count = Regex.Matches(fileName, detailName).Count;

if (count > 0)
{
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Match!");
}
```

2nd try: Doesn't work

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(fileName, detailName))
```

or doesn't work

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(searchPattern, source))
{
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Matches: " + counter++);
}
```

I've noticed something, Regex doesn't work like this way. There's no recognition on the variables:

```
String source = detailName;

String searchPattern = fileName;
```

Only works when the variables are like this:

```
String source = "Top Senders By Total Threat Messages";

String searchPattern = "Incoming Mail Domains Top Senders By Total Threat Messages";
```

But, this won't work for me, I need them to evaluate as a implicit (Non-Literal) String, not as a explicit (Literal) one, 
cause the variables change everytime.

There's a way to get to it please?

Comment: I think you are confused about what regex does

Comment: You should read the doc first before throwing strings in: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Regular Expressions aren't for comparing how closely two strings match.

Comment: Well your first try should work if you had a correct pattern. Could you please update your question and tell us what do you want to achieve? I imagine that replacing whitespaces for '|' in pattern might help you, but I really do not understand what(or why) do you want to do with this regex. E.g. take last two strings in your question (source and searchPattern) and tell us what should be the count and how do you achieve that.

Comment: The user loads a .csv to a DataGrid. I just want the searchPattern (Incoming file) to have the most of the strings of the source's. I wanna know how to do that, how many matches are between them. I need to check at least 3 of them. Of course, the searchPattern change since every submit like source.

Comment: @MAC293 I do not understand. Could you give me a string examples? Like how does string 1 look, how does string 2 look and what should be the result.

Comment: String source and searchPattern are dynamic variables that have a new value everytime on submit.

Comment: String source looks like: "Top Senders By Total Threat Messages" and searchPattern: "Incoming Mail Domains Top Senders By Total Threat Messages". I just wanna know how many matches are between them. searchPattern is the incoming variable, while the source is the one who is evaluated, i.e., How many common Strings of source, searchPattern has, and I need the quantity. I was using Regex, but, it doesn't suply the requeriments. Both are String returned values. There's a way to it?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all - you probably do not need regex (still I recommend to read about regex https://www.regular-expressions.info/).

I guess that you need to count how many words are contained in both strings. What your comments neither question says is if you want to count the same word twice or just once.

Here you can find basic sample:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace SearchLinq
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string source = "Top Senders By Total Threat Messages";
            string find = "Incoming Mail Domains Top Senders By Total Threat Messages";

            // first possible solution
            int result = 0;
            foreach (string word in find.Split(' '))
            {
                if (source.Contains(word))
                {
                    result++;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(result);

            // second possible solution
            int result2 = find.Split(' ').Count(w => source.Contains(w));
            Console.WriteLine(result2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @MAC293 I am glad it helped you. Please mark this as the answer.